# Mac OSX py2app multprocessing error: Unknown option --multiprocessing-fork

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pyinstaller, py2exe, py2app

I am trying to generate a .app file from a Python-based GUI application developed in kivy. I am using multiprocessing to start separate processes or windows. It works well when i run it using python command but gives me the error below after generating .app file from py2app:

```
unknown option --multiprocessing-fork
usage: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
```

I have seen other threads where people mentioned using main function and calling `multiprocessing.support_freeze()` which I have tried already but no luck.

It's only working on my global Python3 environment when I am running the application using Python3. It's NOT working in virtual environments as well as the anaconda environment.

Thank you.

Comment: FWIW, [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support) say _"[freeze_support()] has no effect when invoked on any operating system other than Windows"_.